# How to find the hours difference between two dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the documents in following structure saved in my mongodb.

> UserLogs

```
{
"_id":"111",
"studentID" : "1",
"loginTime" : "2019-05-01 09:40:00",
"logoutTime" : "2019-05-01 19:40:00"
},
{
"_id":"222",
"studentID" : "1",
"loginTime" : "2019-05-02 09:40:00",
"logoutTime" : "2019-05-02 20:40:00"
},
{
"_id":"333",
"studentID" : "2",
"loginTime" : "2019-05-02 09:40:00",
"logoutTime" : "2019-05-02 20:40:00"
}
```

is it possible to query for documents where the period of time between loginTime and logoutTime.**eg: grater than 20 hrs**

`mongodb version = 3.4`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "difference": {
      "$divide": [
        { "$subtract": ["$logoutTime", "$loginTime"] },
        60 * 1000 * 60
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$studentID",
    "totalDifference": { "$sum": "$difference" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "totalDifference": { "$gte": 20 }}}
])
```

You have to just [**`$subtract`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) `loginTime` from `logoutTime` and it will give you the subtracted timestamp and then just [**`$divide`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) it with `3600000` to get the time in hours.

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gBAxlJAqxBe)

Comment: Can u please check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102636/how-to-join-the-two-table-it-is-in-two-different-db-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

Since mongoDB version 5.0 you can simply use `$dateDiff`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      hoursDiff: {
        $dateDiff: {
          startDate: {$toDate: "$loginTime"},
          endDate: {$toDate: "$logoutTime"},
          unit: "hour"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {hoursDiff: {$gte: 20}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r76YH7fMAop)