How to subtract two dates and time in Node.js?
I want to achieve the following when I cancel my subscription:

nextBillingTime: 2024-05-10T14:59:58.582+00:00
paypalSubscriptionCancelledAt: 2024-05-07T11:59:18.000+00:00
subscriptionPeriodDuration: 3 days, 3 hours, 0 minutes, 40 seconds

I have the following code:
paypalRouter.post("/cancel-subscription/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const webhookEvent = req.body;

    if (verifyResponse.data.verification_status === "SUCCESS") {
      if (webhookEvent.event_type === "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED") {
        const userId = webhookEvent.resource.custom_id;
        const subscriptionId = webhookEvent.resource.id;
        const nextBillingTime = webhookEvent.resource.billing_info.next_billing_time;
        const paypalSubscriptionCancelledAt = webhookEvent.resource.status_update_time;

        try {
          const updatedUserCancelSubscription = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: userId, subscriptionId: subscriptionId },
            {
              $set: {
                suscriptionStatusCancelled: true,
                subscriptionStatusPending: false,
                subscriptionStatusConfirmed: false,
                nextBillingTime: nextBillingTime,
                isPremium: true,
                paypalSubscriptionCancelledAt: paypalSubscriptionCancelledAt,
                subscriptionPeriodDuration:
              },
            },
            { new: true }
          );

          // ... (other code)
        } catch (error) {
          // ... (error handling)
        }
      }
    } else {
      // ... (other code)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // ... (error handling)
  }
});

I need help calculating the subscriptionPeriodDuration using the nextBillingTime and paypalSubscriptionCancelledAt dates.

...how precise do you need this to be? It's completely trivial to get the milliseconds between two datetimes: date1 - date2. If that's what you need then that's fine. If you need the exact format you ask for, and you need to correctly handle daylight savings time and every other day/minute/second related edge case, then I'd suggest getting a library to do the lifting for you. Also, if you're getting this data from a database consider that many databases (e.g. postgres) have an INTERVAL data type, and it maybe easier to do it in SQL than JS.

Hello, I'm using MongoDB as my database of choice. When you mention, "then I'd suggest getting a library to do the lifting for you". I tried implementing moment package, but it didn't work because when I canceled my subscription, it immediately sets  nextBillingTime to today's date and hour and doesn't maintain my previous nextBillingTime date when I activate my subscription in the past.

You shared a lot of code that's not really relevant to the problem. Try to reduce your code snippet to the absolute minimum of what you tried to do. This should be 1 or 2 statements along with a console.log

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101773/how-to-find-the-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-mongodb

Thank you all for the help. After a bit of struggle, I realized that my logic was incorrect. Instead of focusing on PayPalSubscriptionCancelledAt and subscriptionPeriodDuration, which are static dates, I should create a dynamic date to update nextBillingTime according to my logic. In my case, I created a new property in my mongoose.Schema() getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh, which is a dynamic date and updates each day thanks to node-cron, and I can create the desired logic. Here is the solution to my problem:
getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh:{
    type: Date,
    required: false,
},

Implementing node-cron
let cronJobs = {};


if (!cronJobs[userId]) {

          //* this is updated each second
        // cronJobs[userId] = cron.schedule("* * * * * *", async () => {
         //* this is updated each day
          cronJobs[userId] = cron.schedule("0 0 * * *", async () => {

          try {
            // const users = await User.find({ suscriptionStatusCancelled: true });
            const user = await User.findById(userId);
            if (!user) {
              console.log(`User not found: ${userId}. Stopping cron job.`);
              cronJobs[userId].stop();
              delete cronJobs[userId];
              return;
            }
            user.getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh = new Date();
            console.log(`Updated getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh for user: ${user._id} to ${user.getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh}`);

              if (user.suscriptionStatusCancelled == true && user.getCurrentTimeAfterRefresh > user.nextBillingTime) {
                user.isPremium = false;
                console.log(`Subscription expired for user: ${user._id}. Stopping cron job.`);

                 // Stop the cron job and delete it from the object
                 cronJobs[user._id].stop();
                 delete cronJobs[user._id];
              }
              
              await user.save();
            

            console.log("Updated subscription times and statuses for cancelled subscriptions");
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error updating subscription times and statuses:", error);
          }
        });
      }


      var d1 = new Date('2024-05-10T14:59:58.582+00:00'), d2 = new Date('2024-05-07T11:59:18.000+00:00'); 

      var diff = d1 - d2

moment is not up to par anymore. Look at their docs and they will give you a bunch of reasons not to use it.
I still use dayjs, but the later ones you should look at are luxon or date-fns.
Check out math with dates on luxon's docs here:
https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/math
